# Как правильно настроить в JACKSON DeserializationConfig

Tags: java

Имеется официальная документация: [JSON-to-Java mapping features](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesDeserialization).

Интересует следующая вещь: во входящем потоке (строке) есть лишние поля, которых нет в объекте, в который мы будем раскладывать эту строку. Если просто выполнять программу, то выдает ошибку, т.к. у объекта не хватает полей. Какой директивой можно отключить, чтобы программа не "ругалась" на лишние поля в приходящей строке?

**Добавлено.**

Правильно ли я понял? Вот это ли мне надо?

> FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES (default: true) Used to control whether encountering of unknown properties (one for which there is no setter; and there is no fallback "any setter" method defined using @JsonAnySetter annotation) should result in a JsonMappingException (when enabled), or just quietly ignored (when disabled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно так:

```
FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES (false)
```